# Symbolic Variables with parenthesis

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

If I create a symbolic matrix:

```
A = sym('A',[2 3])
```

I will get a matrix like this

```
A1_1 A1_2 A1_3
A2_1 A2_2 A2_3
```

**Is there a way to have it with parenthesis (for future substitutions)?**

Such as:

```
A(1;1) A(1;2) A(1;3) 
A(2;1) A(2;2) A(2;3)
```

**EDIT:**
I tried what is explained [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/creating-symbolic-variables-and-expressions.html#brvhmob-1), but if I write

```
A = sym('A(%d;%d)',[2 3])
```

I get an error:

```
Symbolic matrix base name must be a simple variable name.
```

What I want to do is actually to create a large set of symbolic equations (a Jacobian) and then copy and paste it as the Jacobian in my system, where variables will be A(1,1) and not A11 or A1_1. I don't want to evaluate the function or substitute the values, I want the names to be the same so they look like "regular" numeric variables.
One way to do this would be a "find and substitute" thing, but for hundreds of variables it may become boring...

Hope this explains my problem!

Comment: Isn't `A` when you run `A = sym('A',[2 3])` already what you want? You can index it.

Comment: @Daniel I edited my post to better explain what I need this for!

Comment: Yes but you can already use `A(1,1)`, i don't understand the problem of having two labels for the same thing.

Comment: Let's say that I write a function with the first value. `f = A1_1 + 456`
What I want to do is to physically copy the expression `f`, and paste it in a function `g`, which contains `A(1,1)` (with the same physical meaning). I just want `f` to have directly `A(1,1)` in it, without having to manually substitute it.

Comment: You do realize that the reason parentheses aren't allowed is that they'd turn the symbolic variable (`sym`) into a symbolic function (`symfun`)? Is that what you want? The problem is that most symbolic math function –including `jacobian`– operate on symbolic variables. So unless you're manipulating and calculating things yourself, such a scheme may not help.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols are what you substitute for. your matrix looks like this:

[A11  A12  A13]
[A21  A22  A23]

and it is called A. Thus, A(1,1)=A11  and A(1,2)=A12 and so on.

so whenever you want to substitute all you do is assign the value. for example let the matrix be A[1 2;3 4] then,

`A(1,1)=1;`

```
A(1,2)=2;

A(2,1)=3;

A(2,2)=4;
```

the values are assigned manually. I believe it should work

Comment: Good point,  and that works. But what I want to do is actually to create a large set of symbolic equations (a Jacobian) and then copy and paste it as the Jacobian in my system, where variables will be A(1,1) and not A11 or A1_1.
So I actually do not want the functions to be evaluated directly, I want the values to look like they come from a matrix so that I can substitute the actual values (always changing). I'm not sure if I've been clear...

Comment: if the you have your jacobian and the process is simply substitution of values then I would prefer using variables. if however, you want MATLAB to evaluate derivatives in the jacobian I suggest writing the equations individually and differentiating partially each one then simplifying and saving the results to variables which can then be assembled into a matrix. I hope that I understood what you really wanted to do sorry for the late reply